# Best approach and efficient way to merge two array of object in to single array

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have two arrays of object. These two array contain huge data. I want to merge this two array into one. What is the efficient way to do this?

ex:

```
var firstArray= [ {id:1, a:'b'}
                  {id:2, c:'d'}
                  ...
                ]

var secondArray= [ {id:1, z:'1'}
                   {id:2, y:'2'}
                   ...
                 ]
```

Output should look like:

```
var resultingArray= [ {id:1, a:'b',z:'1'}
                      {id:2, c:'d',y:'2'}
                      ...
                    ]
```

Comment: `for` loop is the most efficient way.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/KyleAMathews/deepmerge , is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: it will take more time. if an array have n item and other have m item then it will loop n*m time.which take more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584377/2466782):

```
function arrayUnique(array) {
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};

var array1 = ["Vijendra","Singh"];
var array2 = ["Singh", "Shakya"];
    // Merges both arrays and gets unique items
var array3 = arrayUnique(array1.concat(array2));
```